# with redis-rails, how to delete all but sessions cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, redis, redis-rails

Rails 5.1 app, redis-rails gem 5.0.2

Gemfile

```
gem "rails", "~> 5.1"
gem "redis-rails"
```

in production.rb

```
config.cache_store = :redis_store, ENV.fetch("REDISCLOUD_URL")
```

in session_store.rb

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :redis_store, servers: [ENV.fetch("REDISCLOUD_URL")]
```

I would like to be able to clear cache time to time and I can run

```
Rails.cache.clear
```

for that. However, it clears everything and I don't want to remove sessions.

I tried namespaces but can't find much of documentation anywhere (https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rails)

What commands, configs, approach I can take to solve this?
Thank you.

Comment: I coded a small tools to clear the cache: https://github.com/BorisBresciani/rails_web_cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can get all cache keys

```
Rails.cache.instance_variable_get(:@data).keys
```

and use it in combination with [delete_entry](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c539c684aa0fc08769304746e1702aa1b4ddd4c8/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache/file_store.rb#L96) excluding the session keys.